# When adding slds-button_success, icon shifts to the right

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I have a lightning:buttonIcon

```
<lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:setup" alternativeText="nah" class="bigIcon slds-button_success slds-icon_large"/>
```

with a custom css class:

```
.THIS.bigIcon svg {
width: 3rem;
height: 3rem;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left:10px;
}
```

everything displays fine without slds-button_success. But when that class is added all the icons shift to the right in the button. Why could that be ?